# SQL table is remembering data that has been deleted (MVC/C#)

Tags: c#, sql

I've deleted one of the registered users from the data base manually, by right-clicking on the table row itself and selecting the delete option. Now I am trying to register the same user again with exactly the same email that this particular user use to be registered before. When I run the registration process, the email duplicate method is constantly returning true for some reason. If I try to use any other email for registering it works like charm. Any idea why is this happening?

**Email validation method**

```
 private static bool EmailIsRegistered(string email)
    {
        using (var data = new HospitalDBDataContext())
        {
            if (data.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) data.Connection.Open();

            var match = data.Staffs.Any(x => x.Email.Equals(email));

            if (data.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) data.Connection.Close();
            data.Dispose();

            return match;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you restarted the application? The O/R mapper might still cache this record.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yep I have.

Comment: Can you try running a query directly on the database for that email? Like WHERE email = 'email@example.com' and double-check that there are no results?

Comment: Stupid question, but is the user really in this Staffs table (no Users table)? Are there 2 DBs?

Comment: @Cassie When I run a direct query there are no results indeed.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yes it is the same table, I've just used the term User up there in the paragraph.

Comment: why not just re-write the method to do a query on the database directly passing in the email address as a parameter.. vs struggling with why the Match function along with the `.Any` extension methods is not working

Comment: If none of the simple suggestions above work, you might need to provide more information in order to help us help you.

Comment: Are you hitting this method with ajax call? Ajax calls gets cached, so even if you change record in database you might get "old" result. Btw, if that is not the case, use sql server profiler and see what is going on in the db when you call that method.